# How do I resolve an aditional proxy

Tags: ubuntu, proxy

I have Ubuntu downloaded and installed.  I input my http(s)_proxy information into my `/etc/bash.bashrc` as well as my `apt/apt.conf` and that got me past the first hurdle, but now I'm clueless on how to get past the second.

I have successfully pinged internal machines and that works just fine.

I try to do a ping on "www.google.com" and i get "unknown host www.google.com"

when i execute add-apt-repository ppa: command, i get past the first part and press enter, then I get

```
requesting key 4C9D234C from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
?: keyserver.ubuntu.com: Host not found
```

can anyone help me around this hurdle?

Comment: This would be more appropriate on [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your system lacks properly defined DNS server. Take a look at the etc/resolv.conf file, is there a name server defined? If it is, make sure it's reacheble itself by simple ping command. If not, you may always add it with a simple notation like

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Additional diagnostics may be performed with the [Dig](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/dig.1.html) tool

Comment: I have 3 nameservers with one of them being localhost (127.0.0.1).  my connection-specific DNS that I have on my windows machine is listed under a "search" instead of a nameserver.  I also have a warning to not edit the file by hand as my changes will be overwritten

Comment: So i used the Dig tool and the 3 nameservers returned status of NXDOMAIN and the "search" address returned "noerror" so how do I get my search address to be my DNS service?

Comment: That means you're using 12.04, where DNS lookup configuration has been changed significantly. Localhost record is pointing to local dns server, so we'd better configure it instead, not to get our changes overwritten. Try adding _server=your_search_address_ to your _/run/nm-dns-dnsmasq.conf_ and then restart dnsmasq with _sudo /etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart_